# How to choose a white border for prints?

Tags: printing, prints, borders

I will print some images on an aluminum plate. I saw prints on aluminum absolutely without a white border and with white borders with widths until 12 cm. The size will be around 90x60.

Are there any rules for choosing the white border around prints? Or is this only a question of an individual taste?

Comment: How do you plan to mount and display? Framed? Hung bare with no framing? something else?

Comment: bare, no framing, with a gap of 2cm between the wall and print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's purely a question of taste.

If you are creating the print for your own personal satisfaction and enjoyment, it's a question of your individual taste.

If you are creating the print for a specific client, it's a question of the client's individual taste (unless for whatever reason you do not want your image displayed in the way they desire).

If you are creating the print to offer for sale to a wide number of potential buyers, it's a question of many individuals' taste.

Comment: I saw different prints and can't decide (I wonder, because usually I'm a man of fast decisions). Are there any pro/contra ?

Comment: @Evgeniy, as Michael mention it's your taste. Create in any editor flat file with colour of your wall, then add your image w/o borders, add borders, thin, thick and see what YOU like.